# Composer autoload not working

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I'm using composer autoload for a mvc framework I've built. I've tested it and works on a Vagrant environment (config: http://pastebin.com/aAs2TFMh) and even on Windows.

I get this error: `{"error":{"type":"Whoops\\Exception\\ErrorException","message":"Class 'Elysium\\Controllers\\Error' not found","file":"\/home\/glendme\/public_html\/clubsmade\/src\/elysium\/core\/Router.php","line":99}}`

However when I deployed it on my vps with Ubuntu 13.04+php5.4 it started giving class not found errors. Same happened when I put it on a shared host.

I tried self-update, removing vendor dir and composer install again at no avail.

Here's my composer.json,

```
{
"name": "glend/elysium",
"description": "PHP MVC Framework.",
"version" : "0.1.0-dev",
"keywords" : ["mvc", "framework", "elysium", "glend"],
"homepage" : "http://mvc.blueberry.al",
"license" : "GPL-3.0+",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Glend Gjermeni",
        "email": "contact@glend.me",
        "homepage": "http://glend.me",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
],
"support": {
    "email": "support@blueberry.al"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Elysium": "src/"}
},
"require": {
    "filp/whoops": "1.*",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "*",
    "vlucas/valitron": "1.1.5",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "1.0.3"
}
```

}

And Router.php:

```
    <?php

namespace Elysium\Core;
use Elysium\Controllers;

/**
 * Manages all routing and URL requests for the framework.
 * @package Elysium\Core
 */
class Router
{
    private $url, $controller, $method, $params;
    private $allowedChars = array('-', '_', '/', '\\', '.');

    /**
     * Reads the passed URL from GET request into controller, method and params variables.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!empty($_GET['page']))
        {
            if(ctype_alnum(str_replace($this->allowedChars, '', $_GET['page'])))
            {
                $this->url = $_GET['page'];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Malformed URL");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->url = 'index';
        }

        $this->url = explode('/', $this->url);

        $this->controller = implode('_', array_map('ucfirst', explode('_', str_replace('-', '_', array_shift($this->url)))));
        $this->method = explode('_', str_replace('-', '_', array_shift($this->url)));

        for($i = 1; $i < count($this->method); $i++)
        {
            ucfirst($this->method[$i]);
        }

        $this->method = implode('_', $this->method);
        $this->params = &$this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes correct controller based on URL requested.
     */
    public function commit()
    {
        $class = "Elysium\\Controllers\\$this->controller";

        if(class_exists($class))
        {
            if(method_exists($class, $this->method))
            {
                if(empty($this->params))
                {

                    $ctrl = new $class;
                    $ctrl->{$this->method}();
                }
                else
                {
                    $ctrl = new $class;
                    $ctrl->{$this->method}($this->params);
                }
            }
            else if(empty($this->method))
            {
                $ctrl = new $class;
                $ctrl->index();
            }
            else
            {
                self::error(404);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self::error(404);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes default Error controller based on error code provided and shows the appropriate error page.
     * @param $code
     */
    public static function error($code)
    {
        switch($code)
        {
            case 404:
            {
                $ctrl = new Controllers\Error();
                $ctrl->notFound();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your info explains what you are experiencing. Be specific. List the exact error message, list the code line it is on, and list the class that is supposed to be missing, and where it is located.

Comment: @Sven I'm sorry for not including the error, but you won't get much from the line of code, it's just a class being instiated. I added them now, and all classes are missing not just one, it's not autoloading anything.

Comment: You've probably got a mismatch on the case of the letters for the namespace. The namespace is used as part of the path - Windows doesn't care about case, Linux is case specific.

Comment: @Danack you are right, I have it fixed already but forgot to post here. psr-0 needs folder names to be exact with namespaces. But my dev environment wasn't windows but ubuntu 12.04. Weird!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it myself, the folder name must have uppercase letter just like the namespaces if you're adhering to PSR-0. If you don't want to change you can use composer's classmap.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but had no evidence in your question.